# Українські меми в словниках?

Tags: словники, сленг

В якому рецензованому словнику можна знайти сучасну українську інтернет мову? Наприклад, для російського слова "лол" [стаття на Wikitionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB) посилається на "Словарь языка интернета.ru / под редакцией М. А. Кронгауза.", але український варіант "ліл" ніде обґрунтувати.

Comment: `lol` - не російський. Думаю, що якщо правильно все налаштувати, то першою буде відповідь схожа на цю: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpl9h.png Де `lol` - "laughing out loud". Тобто методи пошуку неправильні.

Comment: це трошки не по темі питання, але "лол" в інтернет сленгу - уже давно не тільки транслітерація. http://lurkmore.to/LOL надає інші приклади: "ну ти й лол", "лолка", "ололо", та й сам "ліл" - корінь всюди один.

Comment: Луркмор - російський сайт, тому всі похідні слова доводять лише що на основі запозичення створюються нові слова ("лол" - запозичення з англійської, "лолка" - слово створене на основі запозичення). Так само "кілер" - запозичення, "кілерський" - вже українське слово створене на основі запозичення. Чому "лол" має при цьому запозичуватись із російської, а не напряму з англійської і до того ж ставати "ліл" - не дуже зрозуміло. Це схоже на "подкаст", який походить від назви плеєра iPod, а не від російського "под" і чомусь має ставати в український "підкастом", наче "под" переклали як "під".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

На жаль, як такого (реальної книги) словника мемів українською мовою не існує. Однак, є сайт [Енциклопедія Драматика](https://drama.kropyva.ch/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) - "*енциклопедія мемів, Інтернет-фольклору і різного цікавого з реального життя та просторів Мережі*".

Також маємо [Файна Меморія](http://ukrmemoria.com/) — "і*нтернет-енциклопедія, створена для лулзів. Канонічно вважається, що Файна Меморія - це енциклопедія інтернет-мемів*".

На українській Вікіпедії є [сторінка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA_%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B2) присвячена деяким мемам.

Залишається лише зібрати всі ці меми і випустити такий словник. Однак, чи це можливо, я не знаю.

Comment: є ще myslovo, хоч вони не лише по мемах, але й словник, який подає росвікіпедія у питання, не лише по мемах

Answer (score 2):

На сайті [SlangZone](https://www.slangzone.net/) можна додавати свої визначення слів чи словосполучень, він підтримує відформатований текст, який дозволяє також вставляти відео, наприклад, з Ютубу. Також можна додавати свої картинки чи навіть ґіфки. Також є можливість додавати коментарі, якщо щось незрозуміло або хочеться доповнити існуючий контент.

Comment: А SlangZone **рецензований**? (Якщо ні, то відповідь однаково корисна, але варто прямо попередити в тексті, бо запитання було саме про рецензований.)

Comment: @Sasha є можливість додавати коментарі і свої визначення того ж самого слова/словосполучення, до того ж, можна голосувати чи певний варіант визначення є відповідним, таким чином рецензію робить спільнота.